# Powershell - If Else Error Handling - Why is the pipe empty

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am attempting to find which shared mailboxes belong to specific security groups, then output the box followed by the security group (possibly more than one group). However, many of the accounts have different spellings in AD (some go by name, some by alias, etc), so I wanted to put in a bit of error handling so I could deal with that, however, when I try to pipe to export-csv, it fails with an empty pipe error... I am rubbish at error handling, so here I am... I originally tried if else... , but that was painful as well I can list what I was doing with that, if that is a better method.

My code:

```
$path = "PathTofile"
$SharedBoxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | select alias,name 

ForEach($SharedBox in $SharedBoxes){
Try {
$BoxName = $sharedBox.alias
$perms = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $BoxName |Select-Object name | Where-Object 
{($_.name -eq "SecurityGroup1" -or $_.name -eq "SecurityGroup1"-or $_.name -eq "SecurityGroup1")}
ForEach($perm in $perms){
 [PSCustomObject]@{
    BoxName = $BoxName
    LicenseGroup = $Perm.name
 }}}

 Catch{
 ForEach($perm in $perms){
     [PSCustomObject]@{
        BoxName = $BoxName
        LicenseGroup = "Could Not Locate in AD"}
 }}} | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: Your code is effectively this: `ForEach($SharedBox in $SharedBoxes){ ... } |  Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -append`. You can't pipe from a `foreach` like that. Try something like `$SharedBoxes | ForEach-Object { ... } | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -append`. You'll need to change references to `$SharedBox` to `$_` (e.g. `$BoxName = $_.alias`).

Comment: ok, fair enough. I will give it a try and update this thread. Thanks.